# Google Sheets - multiple columns with auto timestamp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I am creating a sheet that once a job is assigned to someone, the time is automatically input to the cell beside it.... and when complete, the time is automatically put into the cell beside that one.

I have included a picture of the idea I am going for. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies @david322 & neven. I am very new to this stuff and want to one day know it as well as you guys. I am still having issues when i input those scripts. I have attached a link to my sheet. in the highlighted rows you can see what i am trying to accomplish with names and time stamps ............
[MY GOOGLE SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GDq5p5hruBBVWXSk8KwRLOqZp3VxYp3JUmSiJ-rGCws/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What is the issue with those answers? They do put the timestamps in the respective cells.

Comment: @jescanellas for me the problem is i dont know how to edit the script to customize it for my need. The scripts provided i am sure would work, when i paste them into the script area on the sheet and ran it it gave me an error. I am very much a noob and trying to learn from you guys. The name / time stamp on the first line i wrote in mannually just to show what i want all the rows below to be like

Comment: Which error did you get?

Comment: Hi ! I have requested access to your spreadsheet so that I could try to spot the issue and solve it. Could you please accept it? Could you also share or indicate which script are you using (if you are using one of the answers below which one is it)?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the trigger, it should be enough for you to + adjust the condition there.

I don´t know, when you need fixed date?

```
function insert_timestamp() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  var tz = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  if( r.getColumn() != 0 ) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, tz, "dd.MM.yyyy");//"dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an onEdit trigger for the SpreadsheetApp which you can use. Basically, every time you edit a cell, the onEdit function runs and passes and event. You can then check that event against some criteria and gof rom there. The documentation below does not seem up to date, but the code did work for me. Finally, you can then select how you want the date displayed using the format settings in the Spreadsheet.

```
function onEdit( event ) {
  const currentRow = event.range.rowStart;
  const currentCol = event.range.columnStart;
  const value = event.value

  // if it is in in Column F (6) or Column H (8)
  // you could also check the value here against something
  if( currentCol === 6 || currentCol === 8 ){
     // put the current time in the column next to the current one
     SpreadsheetApp.getRange( currentRow, currentCol + 1).setValue( new Date() )
  }

}
```

See here for reference: [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code below to add time stamps just to 6 and 8. but it input a time stamp beside every cell i edit..

```
    function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Work Orders" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 6, 8 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```